# Assign random numbers avoiding blocked numbers from a range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a game where users can win an extra prize if they select a specific a number from the board.

The Game Master chooses a range for the game and the extra prizes are randomly allocated to a number.

However, the extra prizes cannot be allocated:

- to a “blocked number”
- or the same number as another prize

I have a crude way of making sure the first prize doesn’t match.

How can this code be extended to cover all 5 extra prizes?  I am concerned if I just copy the function 5 times it could loop forever?

Would it be better to create to the game range in an array and then remove the values for each prize as they are generated?

```
var gameMinNum = 10;
var gameMaxNum = 125;
var gameBlockedNum = [5,12,66,97,124,129,165,200]

var extraPrizeNum1 = 0;
var extraPrizeNum2 = 0;
var extraPrizeNum3 = 0;
var extraPrizeNum4 = 0;
var extraPrizeNum5 = 0;


function randomGenerator(xUpper,xLower)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(xUpper-xLower+1)+xLower);
}

function PrizeNum1() {

  extraPrizeNum1 = randomGenerator(gameMaxNum,gameMinNum);
  if (gameBlockedNum.includes(extraPrizeNum1)) {
    PrizeNum1();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you store the "extra prices" in separate variables (and not in an array like the "blocked numbers")?

Comment: In the game code, if the selected number matches one of the prizes it will trigger a different congratulations message etc... and I also store additional details in the array.   I tried to simplify describing my problem with the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for used values and take an array for all prices.

```js
function randomGenerator(xUpper, xLower) {
    return function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (xUpper - xLower + 1) + xLower);
    };
}

function getExtraPrices(randomFn, length, blocked) {
    var selected = new Set(blocked);
    return Array.from({ length }, () => {
        var number;
        while (selected.has(number = randomFn())) ;
        selected.add(number);
        return number;
    });
}

var gameMinNum = 10,
    gameMaxNum = 125,
    gameBlockedNum = [5, 12, 66, 97, 124, 129, 165, 200],
    extraPricesCount = 5,
    random = randomGenerator(gameMaxNum, gameMinNum),
    extraPrices = getExtraPrices(random, extraPricesCount, gameBlockedNum);

console.log(extraPrices);
```